# HP Probook touchpad

Tags: 11.10, touchpad, hp

I wrote about this problem some weeks ago, but now the question is: "Why is touchpad works not so good as in windows". I tried some "experiments":

When I use windows and if I accidentally touched touchpad - cursor isn't moving, also no clicks occurring. So in windows working with touchpad is quite normal, but in Ubuntu аf I accidentally touch the touchpad even with my wrist - cursor is moving etc. In Windows, the cursor moves only when I touch it with finger. And... If, for example, I hold one finger on touchpad and simultaneously move the second finger on the touchpad - the cursor doesn't move, however in ubuntu he does. He's "super sensetive" in ubuntu or what?

Also I tried to apply the option in "Mouse and touchpad", which called "Disable touchpad when typing", but nevertheless he isn't disabling when i'm typing...

Note: this option is circled in red frame, i dont know is it a good "sign" )

What can I do to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have got my solution by installing driver provided by hp. plz have this link for the deb file I have installed.--
 http://ubuntuone.com/07AeUny10786C5SoQjp6wB

Comment: Thanks, but I have 64-bit Ubuntu, do you have the 64-bit version of this driver?

Comment: Try This driver

Comment: This driver is for 32-bit OS version.

Comment: @user66904 Where did you get the driver originally? Was it somewhere at hp.com? If so, perhaps you could go to wherever you got it (or tell us where that is), and there might be a 64-bit package as well.